# rows names and columns name of one matrix to another matrix

Tags: r

I have two matrix which are are of same dimension what i wanted achieve is getting row and col of one matrix replace with other

matrix1=

```
      exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
 arun  10     10   15    18
 joy    2     2     5     6
```

matrix2=

```
       "v1"   "v2"  "v3" "v3"
  "1"   12     13    15    16
  "2"   10     12    13    13
```

output=
I wanted replace matrix2 row name and column name with matrix1

```
       exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
  arun   12     13    15    16
  joy    10     12    13    13
```

can anyone suggest me how can I do, new to R
note:
matrix files are very large

Comment: `dimnames(matrix2) <- dimnames(matrix1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transfer the column names using `dimnames<-`

```
dimnames(matrix2) <- dimnames(matrix1)
```

which does the job of

```
rownames(matrix2) <- rownames(matrix1)
colnames(matrix2) <- colnames(matrix1)
```